# Why was a '78 Caddy a controversial choice?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, brothers-bloom

I watched [Brothers Bloom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0844286/) over the weekend. As Stephen and Bang Bang took Bloom to New Jersey to the Ludicrous Mansion in order to show Bloom the next/last big con, after they watch Penelope crash the Lamborghini, they walk down to Stephen's car and Bloom says:

> Is this a '78 Caddy? Hm. Controversial choice."

Why was a '78 Cadillac a controversial choice?

Comment: by the way, that is not a '78 cadillac in the movie. It is a 80's Cadillac Seville bustle-back (slant-back).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found [this interview](http://news.moviefone.com/2010/05/04/rian-johnson-answers-your-movie-club-questions-and-dishes-on-loop/) with the writer and director, [Rian Johnson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0426059/) in which he explains it:

> Could you explain " '78 Caddy? Controversial choice."?
>
> **Rian Johnson**: That was one of the first cars I owned after college. And the "controversial choice" was something a friend of mine used to say, and you would never know whether it was a diss or compliment. You'd have your music on, and they'd nod and say "Hm. Steely Dan. Controversial choice." And you'd want to punch them but not know exactly why.

So it sounds like it's just a joke and there's nothing really controversial about the multitude of cars Cadillac made and sold in 1978.

Answer (score 3):

1978 was the year of the "Iran Cadillac", due to the model being manufactured in Iran. This may make it controversial.